# How do I filter out a value returned from a GET method?

Tags: node.js, typescript, get, angular-ui-router

In my backend, I have a method that retrieves a list of reasons that I create in the admin application. With those reasons created, in my client application I can select the reason for void.

The problem: I have a reason called: "Host System" which needs to be excluded from the UI when the client is selecting a reason for voiding.

This is my .get method:

```
// Get all.
            .get("/", async (ctx) => {
                // Get all void reasons.
                const voidReasons: TypeAssertion.FriendlyObjectType[] = [];
                for (const markerVoidReason of await MarkerVoidReasonRepository.instance.getList(VoidReasonTypes.Void)) {
                    voidReasons.push(this.mapFrom(markerVoidReason));
                }

                ctx.response.body = voidReasons;
            })
```

What I tried: I tried excluding the reason from the get method like this:

```
// Get all.
            .get("/", async (ctx) => {
                // Get all void reasons.
                const voidReasons: TypeAssertion.FriendlyObjectType[] = [];
                for (const markerVoidReason of await MarkerVoidReasonRepository.instance.getList(VoidReasonTypes.Void)) {
                    if (markerVoidReason.name !== "Host System"){
                        voidReasons.push(this.mapFrom(markerVoidReason));
                    }
                }

                ctx.response.body = voidReasons;
            })
```

This solution also removed the reason from the admin application which I don't want. I want to keep the reason in the UI of the admin application but should be removed from the client application as a reason. The client and main use the same endpoint which I think could be the problem. I'm assuming the solution would be to add another get method that calls the client screen and exclude the reason but how can I do that if the endpoint is universal?

Comment: The code that posted doesn't look like Angular. Is that your backend code?

Comment: yes, sorry, it's my backend code.

Comment: Are you saying there are two different front end applications that access the same API? One needs the list to include "Host System" and the other does not? If that's the case, you could handle this a few ways. One could be adding a parameter to the API, another could be to just filter out what you don't want on the client side.